# Where might I find a scanned handwritten copy of Ramanujan's second letter to Hardy?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ho.history-overview

I am giving a lecture to undergraduates on the lovely identity $$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots = -\frac{1}{12}.$$

Ramanujan wrote in his second letter to Hardy (courtesy [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B)),

"Dear Sir, I am very much gratified on perusing your letter of the 8th February 1913. I was expecting a reply from you similar to the one which a Mathematics Professor at London wrote asking me to study carefully Bromwich's Infinite Series and not fall into the pitfalls of divergent series. … I told him that the sum of an infinite number of terms of the series: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + · · · = −1/12 under my theory. If I tell you this you will at once point out to me the lunatic asylum as my goal. I dilate on this simply to convince you that you will not be able to follow my methods of proof if I indicate the lines on which I proceed in a single letter. …"

Does anyone know where I might find a scanned copy of this or closely related material, in Ramanujan's handwriting? Bruce Berndt kindly pointed me to a typeset version, and much else related of extreme interest -- but I would love to use the original in my lecture, if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Bruce Berndt is probably the mathematician best connected to Ramanujan's legacy, but you could also try the writer David Leavitt
via the University of Florida (dleavitt@ufl.edu).   He did a lot of digging into archives while writing his novel *The Indian Clerk* based on the interaction of Hardy and Ramanujan at Cambridge.   

Comment: @Jim: Thank you, that is an excellent idea! I read his book and I was a big fan of it.

Comment: A Disappearing Number is a play which has a scene near the beginning that uses much the same wording as the start of your post.  Some undergraduates might find it mathematically inspiring.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.12.02

Comment: ``Srinivasa Ramanujan The Lost Notebook and Other Unpublished Papers,"
Narosa Publishing House, New Delhi, 1988 has photocopies of several letters from Ramanujan to Hardy, but unfortunately not the one you want. 

Comment: The Wikipedia link seems to be broken.  (Not that it's so important, but I had not previously heard that 1+2+3+4+...=-1/12, so I got curious.)

Comment: The only way to get a copy of Ramanujan's letter of February 27, 1913 seems to be to contact Cambridge university library http://janus.lib.cam.ac.uk/db/node.xsp?id=EAD%2FGBR%2F0012%2FMS%20Add.7011 .
But remember: *If* it is possible, to attach a finite value to this sum, *then* the value is -1/12. See also G. Edgar's application of one of the "algorithms" in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12 which casts some doubt on the uniqueness of such "results".


Comment: Wikipedia seems OK. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: I mean, proof, history (Euler), picture from R's letter, it has everything.

Comment: For what it's worth, that image on Wikipedia comes from chapter eight of Ramanujan's notebook, not the letter to Hardy. Note that it does not contain the "lunatic asylum comment". It is available here:
http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/NoteBooks/NoteBook1/chapterVIII/page3.htm
the rest of the notebook is indexed here:
http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/NotebookFirst.htm

Comment: @frankthorne: Check with Bruce.

Answer (score 2):

[This article,](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2016/04/who-was-ramanujan/#:%7E:text=On%20about%20January%2031%2C%201913,only%20%C2%A320%20per%20annum.) by Stephen Wolfram from his book *Idea Makers*, has 9 photo images of Ramanujan's letter to Hardy. Not quite sure if it is the whole of his second letter, but it has the famous -1/12 formula on it.